# Filter by Request Header in Charles Proxy?

Tags: charles-proxy

Is it possible to filter by HTTP request headers in Charles Proxy? I'm able to configure visual highlighting in the sequence list for requests matching the header pattern, but I'd prefer to reduce the list of requests to only those matching the request header pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, It's a limitation from Charles that we couldn't filter by Request/Response Header.

If you don't mind, please check out [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) which has many built-in filters that fit your need.

- **Filter**: URL, Query String, Request Header, Response Header, Body, Method, Status Code, Comment, Color
- **Matching** Rule: Contains, Not Contains, Start With, End With, Equal, Not Equal, Regex

[image: Filter request/response]

**Document**: https://docs.proxyman.io/basic-features/content-filter

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of Proxyman and I hope it answers your question.